# How to use one date-indexed pandas DataFrame to map over another one?

Tags: python, pandas

I have two pandas DataFrames both indexed by date, one by day the other by quarter. One has daily prices and the other has quarterly price deflators.

I want to map over the prices so that they are all deflated. I need to divide each value by the appropriate deflator for the quarter that the day falls into. I made a function for comparing days to quarters but I'm new to pandas and I have no idea how to use it to map over my DataFrame

```
def find_quarter(x):
    date = x.index.to_pydatetime
    y = date.year
    q1 = datetime(y,1,1)
    q2 = datetime(y,4,1)
    q3 = datetime(y,7,1)
    q4 = datetime(y,10,1)
    if date <= q2:
        return q1
    elif date <= q3:
        return q2
    elif date <= q4:
        return q3
    else: 
        return q4
```

These are my DataFrames:

```
price_deflator = Quandl.get("FRED/USAGDPDEFQISMEI")
deflator_values = price_deflator['VALUE']

prices_series = Quandl.get("OFDP/FUTURE_W1", trim_start="1995-12-31", trim_end="2014-12-31")
prices = price_series['Settle']
```

I need something like this:

```
prices['Settle'].map(lambda x: ##find the right deflator VALUE for x and divide x by it)
```

I this should be a straight forward task but I searched the documentation for hours and could not find anything. I'm new to pandas, so maybe I missed something.

I'd appreciate your help!

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, I think you can handle this by reindexing your deflator, something like this:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

# simulate the data for 10 years in DataFrames
qtr = pd.date_range('2000-1-1', periods=40, freq='Q')
days = pd.date_range('2000-1-1', periods=3653, freq='D')
prices = pd.DataFrame(np.random.rand(3653)*10, index=days, columns=['price'])
deflate = pd.DataFrame(np.arange(1,41), index=qtr, columns=['deflator'])

# reindex the deflator from qtrs to days than divide to get deflated price
df2 = deflate.reindex(index=days, method='bfill')
prices['deflator'] = df2['deflator']
prices['deflated price'] = prices['price']/prices['deflator']

# show head and tail
print(prices.head())
print(prices.tail())

               price  deflator  deflated price
2000-01-01  5.111764         1        5.111764
2000-01-02  9.266700         1        9.266700
2000-01-03  5.581109         1        5.581109
2000-01-04  2.962819         1        2.962819
2000-01-05  2.110148         1        2.110148
               price  deflator  deflated price
2009-12-27  6.845248        40        0.171131
2009-12-28  6.032179        40        0.150804
2009-12-29  2.438561        40        0.060964
2009-12-30  4.090140        40        0.102253
2009-12-31  6.058384        40        0.151460
```

You may need to use 'ffill' or 'bfill' for the reindex depending on your deflator time series.